# Dropwizard Hibernate (Database Connections open)

Tags: java, hibernate, dropwizard

1. I have 80 threads running in application.
2. Each thread needs to perform simple insert , update  ,select operations.Below is the code which is used for getting DB access.
3. Problem is almost every openSession opens connection to database causing too many open connections.
4. I need to control these number of open DB connections.We are using dropwizard hibernate's default connection pool.
5. Any suggestions on how to control these connections?

   ```
   import org.hibernate.Session;
   import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
   import org.hibernate.Transaction;
   import org.hibernate.context.internal.ManagedSessionContext;

   public class TransactionManager {
       public static <T> T doInTransaction(TransactionCallable<T> callable) throws Exception {
           T result = null;
           Session session = null;
           Transaction txn = null;
           SessionFactory sessionFactory = ApplicationContext.get().getSessionFactory();
           try {
               session = sessionFactory.openSession();
               txn = session.beginTransaction();
               ManagedSessionContext.bind(session);
               result = callable.execute();
               txn.commit();
           } catch (RuntimeException e) {
               if (txn != null && txn.isActive())
                   txn.rollback();
               throw e;
           } catch (Exception e) {
               if (txn != null && txn.isActive())
                   txn.rollback();
               throw new Exception("TransactionManager failure.");
           } finally {
               if (session != null) {
                   session.close();
                   ManagedSessionContext.unbind(sessionFactory);
               }
           }
           return result;
       }
   }

   TransactionManager.doInTransaction(new TransactionCallable<Connection>() {
       @Override
       public Connection execute() throws Exception {
           return dao.getById(id);
       }
   });
   ```

   > maxWaitForConnection: 2s
   >     validationQuery: select 1
   >     validationQueryTimeout: 3s
   >     minSize: 8
   >     maxSize: 60
   >     checkConnectionWhileIdle: true
   >     evictionInterval: 10s
   >     minIdleTime: 1 minute
   >     checkConnectionOnBorrow: true

Comment: and the question is?

Comment: Need to know how to control openSession to not to open connection everytime

Comment: did you get an answer?